# How can I show images to select on a html form?

Tags: php, html, selectlist

I want to show something like select option, but with images in stead of text. Is that possible?
I get the images src by php. Once you select a image I want to take his src to submit my form.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  Ex:  if you're looking a jQuery solution, then mention it your question (and show your code attempt)... don't just use the [tag:jquery] tag by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps...

```
<select name="selectBox1">
  <option value="img1.png" style="background-image:url(img1.png);">male</option>
  <option value="img2.png" style="background-image:url(img2.png);">female</option>
  <option value="img2.png" style="background-image:url(img3.png);">others</option>
</select>
```

On submitting the form you will get the selected value inside `$_POST["selectBox1"]` post variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
background-image:url(url here)
```

Comment: thanks, but that solution only works on firefox. And i would like to show full image.